# Why does Emacs replace mixed case text with uppercase?

Tags: emacs, regex, find-and-replace

In Emacs, when I replace the following list with regexp `opeN \1 closE`:

```
A001X
B002X
C003X
```

It converts all to uppercase:

```
OPEN A001X CLOSE
OPEN B002X CLOSE
OPEN C003X CLOSE
```

Which is not what I expected. It should be:

```
opeN A001X closE
opeN B002X closE
opeN C003X closE
```

Why does this happen, and how can it be avoided?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

look at definition of query-replace-regexp --> see case-replace.
eg. C-f query-replace-regexp
with

(setq case-replace nil)

you get your expected behaviour